# MATLAB: comparing all elements in three arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have three 1-d arrays where elements are some values and I want to compare every element in one array to all elements in other two.

For example:

```
a=[2,4,6,8,12]
b=[1,3,5,9,10]
c=[3,5,8,11,15]
```

I want to know if there are same values in different arrays (in this case there are 3,5,8)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [answer given by AB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425066/matlabcomparing-all-elements-in-three-arrays/2425911#2425911) is correct, but it is specific for the case when you have **3** arrays that you are comparing. There is another alternative that will easily scale to any number of arrays of arbitrary size. The only assumption is that each individual array contains unique (i.e. non-repeated) values:

```
>> allValues = sort([a(:); b(:); c(:)]);  %# Collect all of the arrays
>> repeatedValues = allValues(diff(allValues) == 0)  %# Find repeated values

repeatedValues =

     3
     5
     8
```

If the arrays contains repeated values, you will need to call [UNIQUE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html) on each of them before using the above solution.

Answer (score 5):

Leo is almost right, should be

```
unique([intersect(a,[b,c]), intersect(b,c)])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
c(ismember(c,a)|ismember(c,b)),

ans =
     3     5     8
```

I think this works for all matrices.

Comment: Hmm, I think I like this best of all the answers. +1 Does it always work?  Looks OK at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

Define what you mean by compare.  If the arrays are of the same length, and you are comparing equality then you can just do `foo == bar` -- it's vectorized.  If you need to compare in the less than/greater than sense, you can do `sign(foo-bar)`.  If the arrays are not the same length and/or you aren't comparing element-wise -- please clarify what you'd like the output of the comparison to be.  For instance,

```
foo = 1:3;
bar = [1,2,4];
baz = 1:2;
sign(repmat(foo',1,length([bar,baz])) - repmat([bar, baz],length(foo),1))
# or, more concisely:
bsxfun(@(x,y)sign(x-y),foo',[bar,baz])
```

does what you ask for, but there is probably a better way depending on what you want as an output.

EDIT (OP clarified question):
To find common elements in the 3 arrays, you can simply do:

```
>> [intersect(a,[b,c]), intersect(b,c)]
ans =
     8     3     5
```

Comment: arrays are of the same lenght,and foo==bar doesnt do what i want,it compares only elements wih same index,what i need is to compare each element from one array with each element in another two

Comment: In that case, to compare e.g. arrays foo and bar you do bsxfun(@eq,foo',bar) (or bsxfun(@(x,y)sign(x-y),foo',bar) -- this gives you a matrix where for row i, it compares ith element of foo to all elements of bar.